# Определение местоположения в Сервисе

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Дело в том что я никогда не имел дело с `сервисами`. И мне сейчас предстоит такая задача. Нужно определять местоположение и в реальном времени чертить маршрут на карте и отправлять на сервер. В `Activity` у меня получилось.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        addMarker();
    }

private void addMarker() {
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
        iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(mLastUpdateTime)));
        options.anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        options.position(currentLatLng);
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
        long atTime = mCurrentLocation.getTime();
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(atTime));
        mCurrLocationMarker.setTitle(mLastUpdateTime);
        Log.d(TAG, "Marker added.............................");
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 18));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
        PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.BLACK)
                .geodesic(true);
        for (int z = 0; z < routePoints.size(); z++) {
            LatLng point = routePoints.get(z);
            pOptions.add(point);
        }
        line = mMap.addPolyline(pOptions);
        routePoints.add(currentLatLng);
        Log.d(TAG, "Zoom done.............................");
    }
```

Но не знаю как это реализовать в `сервисах` при этом аккумулятор много не жрал. Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с такой задачей?

Comment: а какаю задачу вы хотите решить, вынеся определение координат в `Service`?

Comment: Хочу отправлять координаты на сервер каждые 30 секунд. А на Activity на карте начертить линию при открытии

Comment: тогда вам нужно будет куда-то складывать координаты. делаете `Service` имплиментите `LocationListener`, `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, настраиваете `setInterval()` и `setPriority()` и получаете координаты